# Update MyTable with values from AnotherTable (with self join)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm relatively new to SQL and currently making some practical tasks to gain experience and got struggled with an update of my custom overview table with values from another table that contains *join*.

I have an overview table **MyTable** with column *EmployeeID*. **AnotherTable** contains data of employees with *EmployeeID* and their *ManagerID*.

I am able to retrieve *ManagerName* using different join methods, including:

```
SELECT m.first_name
FROM AnotherTable.employees e LEFT JOIN  
     AnotherTable.employees m 
     on m.EmployeeID = e.ManagerID
```

But I am getting stuck updating **MyTable**, as I usually receive errors such as *"single row query returns more than one row"* or *"SQL command not properly ended"*. I've read that Oracle doesnt support *joins* for updating tables. How can I overcome this issue? A sample data would be:

```
MyTable
------------------------------
EmployeeID | SomeOtherColumns| ..
1          |     SomeData    |
2          |     SomeData    |
3          |     SomeData    |
4          |     SomeData    |
5          |     SomeData    |
------------------------------

OtherTable
-------------------------------------
EmployeeID |   Name     | ManagerID |
1          |   Steve    |     -     |
2          |   John     |     1     |
3          |   Peter    |     1     |
4          |   Bob      |     2     |
5          |   Patrick  |     3     |
6          |   Connor   |     1     |
-------------------------------------
```

And the result would be then:

```
MyTable
-------------------------------------------
EmployeeID | SomeOtherColumns |ManagerName|
1          |     SomeData     |     -     |
2          |     SomeData     |   Steve   |
3          |     SomeData     |   Steve   |
4          |     SomeData     |   John    |
5          |     SomeData     |   Peter   |
6          |     SomeData     |   Steve   |
-------------------------------------------
```

As one of the options I tried to use is:

```
update MyTable
set MyTable.ManagerName = ( 
    SELECT
        (m.name) ManagerName
    FROM 
        OtherTable.employees e 
    LEFT JOIN OtherTable.employees m ON
        m.EmployeeID = e.ManagerID 
    )
```

But there I get *"single row query returns more than one row"* error. How is it possible to solve this?

Comment: Don't - this violates third-normal form. Keep the employee name in the table with the other employee data and then when you want to **display** the name use `SELECT ... FROM ... LEFT OUTER JOIN` to include the result. What you do not want to do is duplicate the data as then it has the potential to become out-of-sync.

Comment: But what if my goal is to create a separate dataset? Fx I need to create a dataset containing values from 3 different tables? Such as EmployeeID, EmployeeName, ManagerName from Employees table and DepartmentName, DepartmentLocation from Departments table? I know there's an option for subqueries, but it seems too complicated right now for me, so it might be easier to use intermediate tables for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical query:

```sql
UPDATE mytable m
SET managername = (SELECT name
                   FROM   othertable
                   WHERE  LEVEL = 2
                   START WITH employeeid = m.employeeid
                   CONNECT BY PRIOR managerid = employeeid);
```

or a self-join:

```sql
UPDATE mytable m
SET managername = (SELECT om.name
                   FROM   othertable o
                          INNER JOIN othertable om
                          ON (o.managerid = om.employeeid)
                   WHERE  o.employeeid = m.employeeid);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable (EmployeeID, SomeOtherColumns, ManagerName) AS
SELECT LEVEL, 'SomeData', CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(20))
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

CREATE TABLE OtherTable(EmployeeID, Name, ManagerID) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Beryl', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Debra', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Emily', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Fiona', 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Then after either update, `MyTable` contains:

> | EMPLOYEEID | SOMEOTHERCOLUMNS | MANAGERNAME |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | SomeData | *null* |
> | 2 | SomeData | Alice |
> | 3 | SomeData | Alice |
> | 4 | SomeData | Beryl |
> | 5 | SomeData | Carol |

*Note: Keeping this data violates third-normal form; instead, you should keep the employee name in the table with the other employee data and then when you want to display the manager's name use `SELECT ... FROM ... LEFT OUTER JOIN` with a hierarchical query to include the result. What you do not want to do is duplicate the data as then it has the potential to become out-of-sync when something changes.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6ab6df64046841470e71a7ebaf399cb9)*

Comment: While it looks complicated, it does the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AnonymousUser I'm not sure the second option in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6ab6df64046841470e71a7ebaf399cb9) is less "complicated" but it only uses a self-join so it may seem to be less complicated; however, it may be less efficient than a hierarchical query.